# return a single view from different action with different parameter mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 action in my Controller named `Shop` in ASP MVC4 web application

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult productSearchReq(FormCollection collection){}
```

and

```
public ActionResult productList() {}
```

But I have a single .cshtml file named `productList.cshtml`

Both the action returning some parameter which is `list` type like

```
List<ProductModel> Set_list = new List<ProductModel>();
```

in action  `productList()` there is no problem when I use `return View(Set_list)`
but how do I send same parameter from 1st action 
If I use `return RedirectToAction("productList", "Shop", Set_list);` It executes 2nd action methods completely and the results changes. Mention that I am doing this for different type of search but in a same format that's why i am using a single `.cshtml` file. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

You can use overloaded method [Controller.View Method (viewName, model)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29).

```
return View("productList", Set_list)
```